# Are we able to explicitly answer questions asking for very specific currency amounts?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

There's a question on our site, [As a web developer, how much should I charge a British company?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/1716/as-a-web-developer-how-much-should-i-charge-a-british-company), that's very well-written and that contains plenty of data points from the asker regarding some research he's done in the web development industry.

However, there are currently 3 close votes on this question from members of our community. Should this question be closed? Why or why not?

Do the answers answer the question? If not, how do we approach this controversial post? If someone were to answer with a specific dollar amount, how do we qualify the answer to be sure it's accurate and helpful to future visitors?

Answer (score 2):

Think of it this way. When I ask for how much to charge someone, is that answer subjective, and subject to change?

When I look back at that question in a year, how likely is it that the answer to that question will be the same?

Indeed, even the most well-written, well-researched question will still get hit by that. They can be interesting questions, or can even attract a massive amount of traffic to the site, but I think it would be in our best interests to disallow these kinds of questions *(obviously, how much should I charge x for y is a **very** common question...)* if they just want a number.

I think that the answers dodging the question and focusing on what is more important (making sure that you charge something you can live off of, not getting ripped off, etc) are mostly the correct kind of answers.

Comment: I would have to agree; I feel they would be useless later on, and too specific to help enough users. I'd like to hear from other users first, though

Answer (score 2):

You can't get a precise answer, but it could be worded into something more general. "How should I decide on a price for a website" is a good question. The currency is not as relevant as the country - someone in the UK will pay many times more than someone in India.

Comment: Do you think it makes a difference that the asker is explicitly limiting the question to the UK?

Comment: Yes, it would, because the answer is very different based on the country. It seems to fall as a "good subjective" question, because people are not simply giving a list of prices.

Comment: That's the primary reason I didn't close it outright. People were actually looking deeper into it and giving good answers. Also, it looks like someone may have reversed their close vote, as there's now only two.